# Python latitude and longitude

Tags: python-requests, latitude-longitude

how can i fetch the latitude, longitude from url 1 - http://api.linear.com/api/iplookup.json
and
pass in url 2 - https://linear.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=28.6331&lon=77.2207&format=json

using python request module with get and post method

```
import requests

data=requests.get("http://api.letgo.com/api/iplookup.json")
k=data.text

bad= ['{','}','"'] 
  
for i in bad: 
    k= k.replace(i, '') 
#printing string without few signs  

l=k.split(",")

for j in l:
    print(j)
```

this is how i change before

```
import requests

url='https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse'
obj={'lat':'28.6331','lon':'77.2207','format':'json'}

op=requests.post(url,params=obj)

op.url
```

Comment: Please format your code as code! See the online help how to do so, or (if you haven't done it) *do the introduction tour*!

Comment: Did below answer work @Magician?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data directly without converting the response to `data.text` first:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.letgo.com/api/iplookup.json'
data = requests.get(url).json()
lat = data['latitude']
lon = data['longitude']

url2 = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse'
params = {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon, 'format': 'json'}
req = requests.post(url2, params=params)
print(req.text)
```